# SQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction() is deprecated

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

When creating a simple SQLite transaction with the latest version of the System.Data.SQLite nuget package, I noticed the intellisense description for the SQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction() method contains "[deprecated]" and starts with the word OBSOLETE (in all caps, scary!).  However, there is no mention of what the new method to begin a transaction is.

I can still call the method just fine, and there isn't even a warning in the IDE, but is there a new way of accomplishing the following that I am unaware of?

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("some sql statement here", conn, trans))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: according to their source code only overloads with `bool deferredLock` param are obsolete. Version you're using is fine. http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/5d691bfc46d3c324

Comment: @DmitryPavliv That just happened to be the default overload the IDE was showing me.  I incorrectly assumed that all overloads we're deprecated before posting, I appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, according to their source code only overloads with param `bool deferredLock` are obsolete. The method you're using is not:

[image]

Source: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/5d691bfc46d3c324